# Prevent gnome from automatically mounting partition when clicked in nautilus

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, nautilus, automount

I have two partitions on a hard drive in my machine that are formatted as ntfs, but must under *no circumstance* be mounted by my Ubuntu installation (unless I do some preparation first). However nautilus happily displays the partitions, and a single click will mount them automatically.

This is very dangerous behaviour, how can I hide the partitions from nautilus and prevent accidentally mounting them by a single stray mouse click?

Thanks

**Update: I have been experimenting with writing udev rules, however I have not been able to get it working. If anybody has the specific steps needed to modify udev as to not show specific partitions, I would really appreciate it.**

Answer (score 0):

You can [write a `udev` rule that prohibits non-root users from mounting the partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/preventing-mounting-some-partition-by-user-gnomeudisk).

You could also hide the partition icons on your desktop by running `gconf-editor` and unchecking `volumes_visible` in `/apps/nautilus/desktop`.

Comment: Hi. I have already hidden volumes on my desktop. (I don't like icons on the desktop.) But they still show up in several places in nautilus. I will have a look at the udev link you provided...